# Using of word this in the parameters of a function

Tags: c#, .net, html-helper

I have two functions :

```
public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt)
```

and

```
public static string Image(HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt)
```

And i'd like to know the role of `this` in the first function and why in this case i have to put the parameter with `this` in the first place?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting downvotes. People need to learn, right?

Those are Extensions, and they have to go into a static class.

For your HtmlHelper object, you could use it with an Extension like this:

```
string retString = objHelper.Image(srcString, altString);
```

If you did not have the Extension, you would have to write:

```
string retString = Image(objHelper, scrString, altString);
```

They both produce the same result.

Comment: Because people also need to search before asking. The very same question has already been asked multiple times.

Comment: If you don't know the `this` keyword is for Extensions, what do you search for? `this` comes up with a lot of hits.

Comment: Just google anything like "c# this keyword parameter" or "c# this keyword method" and you'll find tons of answers and links about extension methods. It's easy to find an answer, and just so more quicker than writing a question.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` is making it an extension method against the `HtmlHelper` class. This is leveraged a lot in MVC where you do something like `@Html.Image` using the Razor syntax. You might recognize one like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(...)
```

Comment: Who's the one downvoting answer, then undoing the downvote right thereafter? Be responsible when you choose to downvote answers, don't just do it on a whim.

Answer (score 1):

It's an extention function call. If you put a this infront of the first parameter, you can call the method as though it were a function of that parameter.
It's worth reading up on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

They can make code so much easier for the next person to read

Answer (score 1):

You have this function:

```
public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt);
```

**This is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on HtmlHelper class instance**

Extension methods are a special kind of `static` method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.

- The first parameter of the method specifies the type that the method operates on;
- It must be preceded with the [`this` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) as it is an Extension Method.

> From MSDN, "The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class and is also used as a modifier of the first parameter of an extension method."

Comment: In BOLD, you say that both of those definitions are Extension Methods, but your text afterwards states an Extension Method must be preceded with the `this` modifier. Some clarification would help.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: I don't see a downvote, just one (+1) and zero (-1). Perhaps they took it away.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. this example clears everything:

```
public static bool BiggerThan(this string theString, int minChars)
{
  return (theString.Length > minChars);
}
```

You can easily use it on string object:

```
var isBigger = "my string is bigger than 20 chars?".BiggerThan(20);
```

Comment: Yeah, it can be handy for strings. But there are so many other uses for it. If you need some examples, just look at the Linq Library